# Show that usual $L^2$ norm is equivalent to arbitrary norm $||\cdot||$ that satisfies 'convergence condition'

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

> Given $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ consider a norm $||\cdot||$ on $L^2$ such that $(L^2,||\cdot||)$ is a Banach space and every $||\cdot||$-convergent sequence has a subsequence that converges almost everywhere. Show that $||\cdot||$ is equivalent to the usual $||\cdot||_2$ norm.

First of all I think it's safe to mention that such $||\cdot||$ norm exists, as $||\cdot||_2$ norm itself is an example. Now consider the following:

Let $I:(L^2,||\cdot||_2)\to (L^2,||\cdot||)$ be the identity map between two normed spaces. Clearly $I$ is linear and bijective, so in the context of inverse mapping theorem it's enough to show that $I$ is a bounded map.

Now suppose that

$$||f_n-f||_2 \to 0 \;\;\; \text{as $n\to\infty$}
$$

and

$$
||f_n-g|| \to 0 \;\;\; \text{as $n\to\infty$} 
$$

If I can show that $f=g$, then it would imply graph of $I$ defined as $G(I)=\{(f,I(f))\in L^2\times L^2: f\in L^2\}$ is closed (we endow usual product norm on product space, $||(f,f)||=||f||_2+||f||$) and by closed graph theorem we are done.

---

So first, we must have a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere, by $||\cdot||_2$ convergence. Also, by given condition there is a subsequence of $f_{n_l}$ that converges to some limit $h$, since $f_n$ is convergent in $||\cdot||$ norm.

But then we would have $h=g$, otherwise $||f_{n_l}-g|| \not\to 0$ as $l\to \infty$, which is contradiction.

So we have two subsequences of $f$ that's converging to two (possibly) different limits - but I'd like to show that in fact they are equal. Now if $f_n$ actually converged almost everywhere, this would be no problem, but without knowing whether it does I cannot just say $f=g$. I think writing something along the line $||f-g||_2$ would be a good starting point, but I cannot make significant progress from there

Comment: "$(L^2,\|.\|)$ is a Banach space" probably means that for any $u,v \in L^2$ : $\|u-v\| = 0 \implies u=v$ in $L^2$ so that $ \|u-v\|_2 = 0$  (because otherwise choosing $\|.\|$ as the $l^2$ norm on a finite dimensional subspace of $L^2$ would be a counter-example)

Comment: @user1952009 No, it means exactly what it says.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich :  my comment is very clear (while this exercice is not) where does it says that $\|.\|$ cannot be the $l^2$ norm on a finite dimensional subspace of $L^2$   ? what is $L^2$ by the way ?

Comment: @user340297, are you familiar with the open mapping theorem?

Comment: You're so close! Yes, this is clear from the Closed Graph Theorem. Hint: Subsequences have sub-subsequences...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, I am - that's equivalent to inverse mapping theorem

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Wow, yes, of course! thanks for the help

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, your comment is clear. The exercise is also perfectly clear and it simply does not say what you say it says. Your counterexample is  not a counterexample.

Comment: @user340297 Nevermind. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, the exercise is clear. "Banach space" is a standard term. By definition, saying $(L^2,||.||)$ is a Banach space says that $||.||$ is a norm on $L^2$ such that the induced metric is complete. That's what it said and that's what it meant. It was clear tto the OP  - he was 99% of the way to a complete solution. His question had nothing to do with what the exercise meant. The statement of the Riemann Hypothesis is clear - that doesn't mean I know how to do it.